# :active for parent div class not working for child div

Tags: css

I have a button made of `divs`; `.parent` div has child divs; one `div` with an icon and other with a `span` for text.

```
<div class="parent" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <div class="child1" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
        <img src="#"/>
    </div>
    <div class="child2" style="width:20px;height:20px;">
        <span>hii</span>
    </div>
</div>


.parent:active{ background: red;}
```

this only works when I click out of child div's and inside parent div.
but I need for the whole area.

This is working fine in chrome but not in IE.
I need a solution that works in both chrome and IE.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you also clarify your first sentence please? I have trouble understanding your sentence construction.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well? Your first sentence is hard to follow.

Comment: `:active` works only from the moment you press down your mouse button til you release it again anyway - sure that’s what you want? And your problem description is really unclear, when I look at this in Chrome, clicking on anything - the image, the text, the space next to them - _all_ trigger the effect.

Comment: in chrome, it's working but it's not working in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an actual button with its active state?

**EDIT:**
I noticed you mentioned this doesn't work in IE, this is because in IE, the clickable area is behind the content you put on the parent div, for whatever reason, honestly I don't understand that very well; but fixes I have found include setting a `::before` and `::after` pseudo-class to the parent div, with the following properties:

```
.parent:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

button:active {
  background-color: red;
}

.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:active {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="#"/>
  <span>Text</span>
</button>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid blue;">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="child2" style="width:20px;height:20px;border:1px solid green;">
    <span>hii</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, My template deals with divs. Can I apply the style to parent when the child is active?

Comment: Well, the idea of using a button was just for semantics, it should work with divs as well, I edited the answer, take a look